# Differentiability of $g:=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ for a $C^1$ function with $f'(0)=0$ NBHM $2008$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $f'(0)=0$.

Define for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$,

$$g(x,y)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$
Pick out the true statements :

- $g$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$
- $g$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$ if and only if $f(0)=0$
- $g$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2- \{ (0,0)\}$

I do not have much idea of differentiation of multivariable calculus.

I just tried out some examples to get some idea..

I have to take some function whose derivative at $0$ has to be zero.

for simplicity I would take $f(x)=x^2$ Then I would get :

> $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ which is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$

This would suggest me that second option has more chances as $f(0)=0$ in this case.

I would now take $f(x)=x^2+1$ then :

> $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1$ which is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$ though $f(0)\neq 0$

So, I would now eliminate second option and third option also...

So, It is now got confirmed that i have to work out to "Prove" that first option is correct.

Now, I have to prove that $g(x,y)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ is differentiable.

I have to look for partial derivatives first :

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}= f'(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}).\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=f'(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}).\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}= f'(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}).\frac{2y}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=f'(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}).\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

I have used here that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$

As $f$ is continuously differentiable, we have $f'$ is continuous and I know that :

$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ are also continuous.

> As $f'$ and $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ are continuous So is the product $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=f'(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}).\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$
>
> As $f'$ and $\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ are continuous So is the product $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=f'(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}).\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

So we have continuous partial derivatives for $g(x,y)$..

So, I am willing to conclude that:

> $g(x,y)$ is  differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$

I would be thankful if some one can confirm if the answer correct.

I would be much more thankful if some one can let me know if there are any gaps in my argument.

This is just a proof verification Question..

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formulas establish that $g$ is $C^1$ away from the origin, but establish nothing at the origin. (Your continuity claim for $x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ certainly fails at the origin.) Check the definition and ask if there is a linear map $Dg(0)\colon \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ with the appropriate properties.

**EDIT:** To wit, we need
$$\lim_{h,k\to 0} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)-\big(\partial g/\partial x(0,0)h+\partial g/\partial y(0,0)k\big)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0. \tag{$\star$}$$
You need to actually go back to the *definition* of partial derivative to compute the partial derivatives of $g$ at $(0,0)$. A sneaky alternative is to guess the answer (hmmm, $0$?) and use the limit ($\star$) to deduce that it must be correct.

Comment: Just now I realize that this my claim for continuity at $0$ is wrong :(... Some one said that if partial derivatives exists then it is differentiable for a function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.. So, even if partial derivatives are not continuous can i confirm differentiability?

Comment: So, given your hypotheses, what is your candidate for the partials of $g$ at the origin? Existence of partials is *not* enough for differentiability, but tells you what the derivative must be if it exists.

Comment: my partial derivatives are as stated in the question $f'(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}).\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and f'(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}).\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}

Comment: No, no. At $(0,0)$!

Comment: I would see $$\lim_{h,k\to 0} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)-\big(\partial g/\partial x(0,0)h+\partial g/\partial y(0,0)k\big)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$as $$\lim_{h,k\to 0} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0))}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}-\lim_{h,k\to 0}\frac{\partial g/\partial x(0,0)h+\partial g/\partial y(0,0)k\big)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$
But then,$f'(0)=0$ so we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=0$ and in particular $\lim_{h,k\to 0} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0))}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$ so only thing i need to  make sure $$\lim_{h,k\to 0}\frac{\partial g/\partial x(0,0)h+\partial g/\partial y(0,0)k\big)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$

Comment: In general, you cannot split those up at all. In this case, your LHS is $0$ (why?), so that tells you what the RHS must be.

Comment: I am sorry..Definition of partial derivative w.r.to $x$ at $(0,0)$ is.. $\lim _{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(h,0)-g(0)}{h}$ which is equal to $\lim _{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(h,0)-g(0)}{h}=\lim _{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=f'(0)=0$..Definition of partial derivative w.r.to $y$ at $(0,0)$ is.. $\lim _{k\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(0,k)-g(0)}{k}$ which is equal to $\lim _{k\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(0,k)-g(0)}{k}=\lim _{k\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(k)-f(0)}{k}=f'(0)=0$  .. so both partial derivatives are zero

Comment: Almost perfect. You need $f(|h|)$.

Comment: Ah.. I should have been more careful....so should i write ...as $|h|\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: That makes no difference. But the limit is still $0$. Be sure you know why :)

Comment: yes yes.. Thank you so much for the wonderful support.... :)

Comment: I have small doubt.. I am little worried to write $ \lim _{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(|h|)-f(0)}{h}=0$ This seems fine to me but...

Comment: You need to split into left- and right-limits.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of clarity and to keep every thing at one place and for my reference, I would like to sum it up :

For $g(x,y)$ to be differentiable at $(0,0)$ we have to see if

$$\lim_{h,k\to 0} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)-\big( g_x(0,0)h+ g_y(0,0)k\big)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$

We first of all find partial derivatives :

$$g_x(a,b)=\lim _{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(a+h,b)-g(a,b)}{h}$$

$$g_y(a,b)=\lim _{k\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(a,b+k)-g(a,b)}{k}$$

at $(0,0)$ we would then have

$$g_x(0,0)=\lim _{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(h,0)-g(0,0)}{h}=\lim _{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(|h|)-f(0)}{h}=0$$

$$g_y(0,0)=\lim _{k\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(0,k)-g(0,0)}{k}=\lim _{k\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(|k|)-f(0)}{k}=0$$

So, we have $g_x(0,0)=0,g_y(0,0)=0$..

So we would then have

$$\lim_{h,k\to 0} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)-\big( g_x(0,0)h+ g_y(0,0)k\big)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\lim_{h,k\to 0} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

As $f'(0)=0$ we would have $$\lim _{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=f'(0)=0$$ and in particular $$\lim_{h,k\to 0} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0))}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$

So we would then have,

$$\lim_{h,k\to 0} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)-\big( g_x(0,0)h+ g_y(0,0)k\big)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\lim_{h,k\to 0} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{h,k\to 0} \frac{g(h,k)-g(0,0)-\big( g_x(0,0)h+ g_y(0,0)k\big)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$

i.e., $g(x,y)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Done :)

P.S : I have checked every thing twice but then if you think there is some argument missing please let me know..

Thank you :)

Comment: You have to do $g(h,k)$ generally, not just $g(h,0)$ or $g(0,k)$. But perhaps it would help to substitute $r=\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$ ? Modify your line after "As $f’(0)=0$".